# Sparql query where clause

Tags: rdf, sparql

I want to get individuals of which #peakHour is "19" AND #peakDay is "Sunday". ( like in SQL it would something be: `SELECT * From abc WHERE peakHour = "19" AND PeakDay  = "Suday"` )

below sparql query is working fine but it is incomplete. I don't know how to add (and #peakDay = "Sunday") to the sparql query

```
SELECT ?x WHERE 
{ ?x <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#filePeakHour> "19" }
```

Please guide me how to add `AND` keyword in WHEREclause of Sparql Query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of examples in the specification, [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#basicpatterns), including one in [2.2 Multiple Matches](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#MultipleMatches):

```
PREFIX foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name ?mbox
WHERE
  { ?x foaf:name ?name .
    ?x foaf:mbox ?mbox }
```

There's no conjunction or join operator in SPARQL.  When you write more than one pattern, they *all* have to match.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502814/1281433) to [sparql join query explanation hows its working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23500140/1281433) for a bit more information about that.  (It's not a great question, but it explains that joins are implicit in SPARQL).  So what would your query look like?

I'm going to use a prefix to make your query easier to read.  You mentioned `#PeakDay` and `#PeekHour`, but your URIs are actually `...#filePeakDay` and `...#filePeakHour`.  Using the prefix, though, you can write just `:PeakHour` and `:PeakDay`.

```
prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#file>

select ?x where {
  ?x :PeakHour "19" .
  ?x :PeakDay "Sunday" .
}
```

If you want, you can use some syntactic sugar to make that a bit shorter:

```
prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#file>

select ?x where {
  ?x :PeakHour "19" ;
     :PeakDay "Sunday" .
}
```